# Calling stored procedure from asp.net and declaration missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

When I tried to call a sp getting below exception..

> System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PLS-00201: identifier 'ULTIMUS.PUSH_PULL_MESSAGE' must be declared
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>
> at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc)
>      at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor, ArrayList& resultParameterOrdinals)
>      at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQueryInternal(Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor)
>      at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at _Default.GetPushPullReply(String msisdn, String sms, String shortcode) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\pushpullapps\Default.aspx.cs:line 73

Currently I am using... below codes..

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
con.ConnectionString = conString;
con.Open();
OracleCommand mycom = new OracleCommand();
mycom.CommandText = "ultimus.push_pull_message";
mycom.Connection = con;
mycom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
saveSer("Calling sp...");
mycom.Parameters.Add("cell_no", OracleType.VarChar, 2000).Value = msisdn;
mycom.Parameters["cell_no"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
mycom.Parameters.Add("msg_txt", OracleType.VarChar, 2000).Value = sms;
mycom.Parameters["msg_txt"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
mycom.Parameters.Add("msg_out", OracleType.VarChar, 2000).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
saveSer("adding parameter...");
mycom.ExecuteNonQuery();
saveSer("Execute successfully....");
String output = mycom.Parameters["msg_out"].Value.ToString();
saveSer("Output found..." + output);
con.Close();
return output;
```

Comment: Make sure you have the stored proc defined with the correct name and that it is accessible from your the login credentials in the connection string.

Comment: I think this means that you have an error on line 1, column 7 of your stored procedure. I can't tell for sure, since you haven't posted your stored procedure!!!

Comment: Actually I havent the store procedure... I have only the access credential..
I have already accessed this SP from php.. but fetching problem  through asp..
thanks

Comment: Take a look here at a more common approach to passing parameters I don't see @ sign in your code with the parameter name. May be this helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What user do you use to connect with to your database? 
If the ultimus is the package name, and the schema the package is in is different as the user you connect with you will have to add the schema as well:

```
 "schemaname.ultimus .push_pull_message";
```